# Storing Google Autocomplete data as customers address

Tags: google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I'm looking for a possible solution to store the autocomplete address returned by Google Autocomplete as the address of the customer account on an website.

Technically, this isn't allowed by the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service, but there are other big companies doing it. Is there a law lacune, or some other way of doing this, maybe with `place_ID`?

Answer (score 1):

Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section 3.2.3(a) of the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values for later use.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#save-id

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id